# Live check doesn't work using PDO

Tags: php, jquery, pdo

I am using JQuery to check if username is in use, however I have some issues. It is always stuck of "Searching". Image below shows exactly what the issue is.

[image]

Register.JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('#username').keyup(function() {

    var username = $(this).val();

    $('#usernameCheck').text('Searching...');

if (username === '')  {
    $('#usernameCheck').text('');
}else {
  $.post('usernamecheck', { username:username }, function(data) {
      $('#usernameCheck').text(data);

  });
}
});
});
```

Register.php:

```
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>Register</title>
    <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='styles.css'>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8/jquery.min.js"></script>         
    <script type="text/javascript" src="JS/register.js"></script>             
    </head>
   </html>

<?php

echo '<form action="register.php?action=registerCheck" method="post" name="formOne">
  <br/><input type="text" id="username" placeholder="Username" maxlength="50" title="Maximum 50 charcters or less."><span id="usernameCheck"></span><br/>
  <br/><input type="password" name="passwordOne" placeholder="Password"  maxlength="60" title="Maximum 60 charcters or less."><br/>
  <br/><input type="password" name="passwordTwo" placeholder="Retype Password" maxlength="60" title="Must be the same as the password field above this."><br/>
  <br/><input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email Address" title="Must be correct in-case admins wish to contact you."><br/>
  <br/><textarea disabled rows="1" cols="4" name="defSpamCheck">'.$spamCheck.'</textarea><br/>   
  <br/><textarea rows="1" cols="30" name="userSpamCheck" placeholder="Enter the 4 digit code above." title="Needed to check for bots."></textarea><br/>            
  <br/><input type="submit" value="Register" onclick="return validate()">
  </form>';
}

function registerCheck() {

global $PDO;  

// All the validations
if (!isset($_POST['username']) || empty($_POST['username'])) {
    echo '<br/>';
    echo '<p class="error">You missed out the usernane field.</p>';
    echo '<a href="register.php">Back</a>';
    endPage();      
} else if (!isset ($_POST['passwordOne']) || empty ($_POST['passwordOne'])) {
    echo '<br/>';
    echo '<p class="error">You missed out the password field.</p>';
    echo '<a href="register.php">Back</a>';
    endPage();
} else if (!isset ($_POST['passwordTwo']) || empty ($_POST['passwordTwo'])) {
    echo '<br/>';
    echo '<p class="error">You missed out the second password field.</p>';
    echo '<a href="register.php">Back</a>';
    endPage();
} else if ($_POST['passwordOne'] != $_POST['passwordTwo']) {
    echo '<br/>';
    echo '<p class="error">Passwords do not match.</p>';
    echo '<a href="register.php">Back</a>';
    endPage();
} else if (!isset ($_POST['email']) || empty ($_POST['email'])) {
    echo '<br/>';
    echo '<p class="error">You missed out the email field.</p>';
    echo '<a href="register.php">Back</a>';  
    endPage();
} else if (!filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
    echo '<br/>';
    echo '<p class="error">Email not valid.</p>';
    echo '<a href="register.php">Back</a>';  
    endPage();        
} else if (!isset ($_POST['userSpamCheck']) || empty ($_POST['userSpamCheck'])) {
    echo '<br/>';
    echo '<p class="error">You missed out the spam check field.</p>';
    echo '<a href="register.php">Back</a>';
    endPage();
} else if (strlen($_POST['username']) > 50) {
    echo '<br/>';
    echo '<p class="error">Username has to be 50 characters or less.</p>';
    echo '<a href="register.php">Back</a>';
    endPage();        
} else if (strlen($_POST['passwordOne']) && strlen($_POST['passwordTwo']) > 60) {
    echo '<br/>';
    echo '<p class="error">Password has to be 60 characters or less.</p>';
    echo '<a href="register.php">Back</a>';
    endPage();         
} else if (strlen($_POST['username']) < 5) {
    echo '<br/>';
    echo '<p class="error">Username has to be greater than 5 characters.</p>';
    echo '<a href="register.php">Back</a>';
    endPage();        
} else if (strlen($_POST['passwordOne']) && strlen($_POST['passwordTwo'])  < 5) {
    echo '<br/>';
    echo '<p class="error">Password has to be greater than 5 characters</p>';
    echo '<a href="register.php">Back</a>';
    endPage();      
} else {
    $username = htmlspecialchars($_POST['username']);

    // Replace all these with $replace
    $sChars = array ("<", ">", "(", ")", "*", "&", "#", ":");
    $replace = ' ';

    // Trim to remove any blank spaces
    trim(str_replace($sChars, $replace, $username));        
    $password = sha1(htmlspecialchars($_POST['passwordOne']));
    $email = htmlspecialchars($_POST['email']);

    $stmtOne = $PDO->prepare("SELECT COUNT(`uID`) uUsername FROM `users` WHERE uUsername=? LIMIT 1");
    $stmtOne->bindParam(1, $username, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmtOne->execute();
    $result = $stmtOne->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    if ($result == 1) {
        echo '<br/>';
        echo '<p class="error">Username already in use, pick another one.</p>';
        echo '<a href="register.php">Back</a>';
        endPage();
    }

   $stmtTwo = $PDO->prepare("INSERT INTO `users` (uUsername, uPassword, uEmail) VALUES (?, ?, ?)");

    if ($stmtTwo->execute(array($username, $password, $email))) {
        echo '<br/>';
        echo '<p class="norm">Account created! You can now log in.</p>';
        header("Refresh:3; URL=login.php");
        endPage();
    } else {
        echo '<br/>';
        echo '<p class="error">We could not create your account, please try again later.</p>';
        header("Refresh:3; URL=login.php");
        endPage();
    }
}
}

?>
```

usernamecheck.php:

```
    <?php

include 'pdo.config.php';
include 'register.php';

global $username;

    $stmtOne = $PDO->query("SELECT COUNT(*) uUsername FROM `users` WHERE uUsername='$username'");
    $rows = $stmtOne->fetchALL();
    $count = count($rows);

    if ($count < 1) { 
        echo 'Username already in use, pick another one';
    } else if ($count == 0) {
        echo 'Username available';
    }


?>
```

But it won't work, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: What does `auth.login.php` do? If the user is registering, they won't be logged in yet.

Comment: Does the script set `$username = $_POST['username']`?

Comment: Are there any errors in the Javascript console?

Comment: @Barmar, No errors, but it should only select that username field, however it selects it all I will post pic again. Shall I post my full register page and you tell me where I should put the code?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by that. I asked if there are error messages coming from the Javascript interpreter.

Comment: @Barmar, added most of register's checks tell me if all my files are correct.

Comment: Is `register.php` the script with the form in it? You shouldn't include the form in the AJAX server.

Comment: @Barmar, Register.php does not include the actual script. That script is kept in register.js which is linked at the top of register.php.

Comment: What is in `include 'register.php'`?

Comment: I need to access the variable $username from register.php so I included it, unless I'm not meant to?

Comment: That's fine, as long as it's not doing anything else that could be interfering. What else is in that script?

Comment: have you checked the Network tab in Developer Tools to see if you're getting a response to the AJAX call?

Comment: @Barmar, Everything in that script is on my post. And no, what does that do?

Comment: It would help if you labeled your post with the filenames. I asked if the PHP script with the form in it was `register.php`, and you said no.

Comment: If `register.php` is the file that begins with `<html>` in your post, then you should not include that in the AJAX server. The AJAX server should only output the result that's needed for the username check, not all the form HTML. You'll need to set `$username` in directly in `usernamecheck.php`, not include the other script to do that.

Comment: What does what do? Developer Tools? It's how you debug Javascript applications. The Network tab shows all the HTTP requests sent by a page, including AJAX calls.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36574/discussion-between-script47-and-barmar)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so my code was right but I had a small but critical error.

$(document).ready(function(){

$('#username').keyup(function() {

```
var username = $(this).val();

$('#usernameCheck').text('Searching...');

if (username === '')  {
$('#usernameCheck').text('');
}else {
$.post('usernamecheck', { username:username }, function(data) {
  $('#usernameCheck').text(data);

});
}
});
});
```

Where it's looking for the file, I put "usernamecheck". It was mean't to be usernamecheck.php. I missed out the file extension.

Answer (score 0):

`$count` is the number of rows. Your query always returns exactly 1 row, since it's just returning a count. Also, both your `if` tests are checking if `$count` is 0 (I think you meant to write `$count == 1` for the first one).

```
$stmtOne = $PDO->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) uUsername FROM `users` WHERE uUsername = :username");
$stmtOne->exec(array('username' => $username));
$row = $stmtOne->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
$count = $row->uUsername;

if ($count == 1) { 
    echo 'Username already in use, pick another one';
} else if ($count == 0) {
    echo 'Username available';
}
```